# How to do VPN split tunneling for urls and IP addresses on Windows 11

Tags: windows, networking, vpn

On Windows 11 I want any traffic going to `long.dns.name.amazonaws.com` (DataGrip Redshift connection) and `http://n.n.n.n:8000/` (Airbyte hosted on EC2 with an elastic ip) to be routed through my VPN, but nothing else.

I disabled *Use default gateway on remote network* but have the following error adding the route:

```
PS C:\> Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName 'xxx' -DestinationPrefix n.n.n.100/24
Add-VpnConnectionRoute:  Invalid parameter DestinationPrefix n.n.n.100/24. : The parameter is incorrect.
```

Will Add-VpnConnectionRoute work with a url address, not an IP address?

Comment: `34.213.245.100/24` why are you specifying a /24 starting at .100? Parameter incorrect indeed.

Comment: @GregAskew for the same reason i'm asking this question, I'm a developer not a network engineer

Comment: As others mentioned, you should step back and state what you are attempting to accomplish. Many organizations have detailed routing tables to accommodate split tunneling workers.

Comment: You aren't being asked what your job is or what you know. You were asked to simply explain what you did. We still don't know if it is a typo or cargo cult copy paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get this behavior exactly. Forwarding packets is always based on IP addresses: The entity that forwards packets checks the destination IP address and selects outgoing interface based on that information.

Only option you have is to route all the IP addresses that this domain name might have via VPN. This means that other domain names that map to that address space get forwarded via the VPN.

I think you need to go a step back and consider what exactly is the issue you are trying to solve with VPN and think of some other solution.

About the error message above: `34.213.245.100/24` is an invalid network specification. `/24` networks always start at `.0` and cover 256 addresses. In your case I think you meant `34.213.245.100/32` to cover a single IP address.